# Struts2 Android Upload Image

Tags: android, file, rest, struts2, upload

We have an Struts2 Webserver which has the jsp way of accepting the file,

but the problem is using Android client the file upload happens by opening HttpConnection(Rest Api's)

can someone help me identify, How can i upload an File using Android client to Struts2 Webserver

Answer (score 1):

Struts2 treats file uploads the same as any Java web app, using multipart/form-data.
Have a look at [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion#post-multipartform-data-and-read-json-with-an-upload-progress-bar), it has a good API for POSTing multipart/form-data.